# Login to Docker image running on a remote machine accessed via Bastion proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, docker

I would like to login to a Docker image that is running on an EC2 instance *$INSTANCE* proxied by a Bastion host *BASTION*   .

My attempt is to use the *to* parameter of *ssh* to get to the proxied host *$INSTANCE* . That is working. But how to then specify the command to execute on that host *$INSTANCE* ?  The following appears to execute the command on the *proxy* bastion host.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/us-prod.ezops.pem -to ServerAliveInterval=50 
     ec2-user@$BASTION -A ssh -to ServerAliveInterval=50 ec2-user@$INSTANCE  
     -t 'clia=$(docker ps | grep clia_lab | cut -d " " -f 1) ; 
          echo "clia is $clia" ; 
         docker exec -it $clia /bin/sh ;'
```

Specifically : the *-t [command]* is apparently not the way to execute *[command]* on the remote instance.

How should the above proxied ssh command be changed to run the interactive session on the remote docker instance ?

Comment: You should debug a problem like this in steps. First, run it with a command like `uname -a`, `ls` or `date>>date.log`, so you can determine whether the command is running, and where. Then advance to a more complex command like `docker ps | grep clia_lab | cut -d " " -f 1` (but still with output to the screen) to verify that it is doing what you expect. If you haven't figured out the problem yet, add the command substitution (`clia=$(` *`blah blah`* `)`) and see what you get. And *tell us* the results. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Try losing the '-t' and just have the command be the last argument (still quoted though).